# Convert NSString to char array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, char

```
const char arr[]="Hello There";
```

I am trying to create a character array as above.

Below, is the code which I use. Is this a correct way to create a char array.

```
-(void) createCharArray:(NSString*) text{
   char arr[text.length];
   for(int i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    arr[i]=[text characterAtIndex:i];
   }
}
```

Do we have to worry about null termination?
Do we have any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Simple: `const char arr[]="Hello There";`.  Of course, if you want to create a char array *from an NSString* then maybe you'd want to look at the spec for NSString and pick one of the several methods it provides.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `UTF8String`. Eg: `[myString UTF8String]`.

Comment: I think UTF8String returns a character array pointer

Comment: It returns a `char*` which you can use like you would use a `char[]`.

Comment: As always with C, "array" is a nebulous term.

Comment: char c[]=[text UTF8String]; throws a error "Array initialiser must be an initialiser list to string literal"

Comment: So use char *c = [text UTF8String]; You want a pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer of characters, not a statically created C string.

Comment: That's right, I forgot about the UTF8String convenience method. That's easier than my suggestion to use getCString:maxLength:encoding with an encoding of NSUTF8StringEncoding. (Voted)

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not the correct way on several levels. NSString supports unicode, which far exceeds the number of possible characters that will fit in a byte array.

You need to use an encoding like UTF8 if yo want to convert unicode to 8 bit characters.

Take a look at the method getCString:maxLength:encoding:, and try using NSUTF8StringEncoding.

That method should do what you want to do with a single call.

Answer (score 3):

Use,

```
NSString *str = @"Hello There";
const char *c = [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This will return a pointer not a array.

Comment: @andyPaul A pointer to chars can be used like a char array (c[0] retruns 'H')

Comment: Not working for non-latin characters.